# C# Asynchronous TCP Listener doesn't cancel loop

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tcplistener

I'm writing a server in C# using the TCPListener class asynchronous. I currently have the following code as my network listener class:

```
public class NetworkListener
{
    private readonly SessionController _sessions;
    private readonly TcpListener _server;

    public NetworkListener(KernelConfiguration configuration, SessionController sessions)
    {
        _server = new TcpListener(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, configuration.Network.port));
        _server.Start();

        _sessions = sessions;
    }

    public async Task StartAccepting(CancellationToken token)
    {
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var client = await _server.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            Console.WriteLine($"New connection from {client.Client.RemoteEndPoint}.");
            _sessions.AddSession(client, Guid.NewGuid(), out var session);
            await session.StartReceiving();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("stop");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _server.Stop();
    }
}
```

As my program.cs I have:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static NetworkListener _networkListener;
    private static CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;

    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        _networkListener = new NetworkListener(new KernelConfiguration(), new SessionController());
        _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        var thread = new Thread(ProgressConsoleCommands);
        thread.Start();

        try
        {
            await _networkListener.StartAccepting(_cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        }
        finally
        {
            _networkListener.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private static void ProgressConsoleCommands()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var command = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(command);

            switch (command)
            {
                case "close":
                    Console.WriteLine("called");
                    _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**What currently happens:**

I start up my program. It starts the TcpListener. I can connect to the port the TcpListener is listening to. When I type in "close" (without the quotes of course), it writes "called". However, "stop" doesn't get written to the console and the TcpListener is still accepting new questions.

**Desired state:**

Whenever I type in "close", it should stop accepting new connections, write "stop" and be out of the loop. Then it should call the Dispose function of my NetworkListener class to stop the TcpListener completely and to dispose it.

Comment: Your explanation what is going wrong is kinda confusing (atleast for me) could you please try to clearify that by editing your post / rephrasing /adding more explanation? You could also have a look at [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) You could try to clearify your problem by stating your **CurrentState** under currentState and **WantedState** under wanted state. I guess that could help me understand your problem :) Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Not completely sure, but you might need to pass the `CancellationToken` to `AcceptTcpClientAsync`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - there's no overload that accepts one, unfortunately. But you're right that that's the sticking point. One (ugly) solution would be to open a loopback connection after causing cancellation so that we know the `Accept` task will complete.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto No it doesn't accept any parameters as far as I see.

Comment: Look at the properties for : _server.Server.

Comment: The async implementations for many classes in the library are unfortunately lacking critical functionality. Just close the listener instead to abort pending async tasks.

Comment: As odyss-jii has pointed out, the socket related functions in the .NET framework are designed very poorly in terms of clean cancellation. I can't quite remember if calling `Stop` on a `TcpListener` will cause any pending "asynchonrously blocking" operations to finish immediately. If not, you can always use the old Begin and End pattern, and wait use the WaitHandle of the AsyncResult to wait in a way that can be canceled by a CancellationToken. You will have pretty much the same problem when reading bytes from the TCP stream.

Comment: I see in the comments the all-too-common collection of poor carpenters blaming their tools. Suffice to say, I've use the various async APIs on `Socket` and `TcpListener` and they work fine, as long as you keep in mind all the usual rules about dealing with sockets. In your own question, it's impossible to provide a good answer, since you haven't provided a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. But, it's clear you've got some problems: you seem to be expecting your cancellation token to have some effect on the `TcpListener` and/or underlying socket, but it obviously can't ...

Comment: ... because those classes never see the token. You've also combined the loop that accepts clients with the one that receives from clients; if you only want to handle one client at a time, this is okay, but either way you need to remember that there are _two_ sockets you're dealing with: the one that listens (created once) and the one that connects to the client (created for each accepted client). Both need to be closed, and the latter needs to be shutdown gracefully, if you want your network operations to complete.

Comment: If you don't know what is meant by "shutdown gracefully", then you haven't spent enough time reading about TCP and sockets

Comment: @PeterDuniho You know very well what the OP wants - a way to cancel a pending `accept()` call. And the answer is either (1) close the socket, or (2) poll on a thread, or (3) `select()`. There is no other way. The same goes for pending reads. The Socket API simply does not support cancellation. This has been known for a long time and improvements have been suggested, see https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/5749 or https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/9698, although the best the .NET could do is mask the underlying problem better (continued)...

Comment: A good workaround that supports cancellation without transitioning the socket to an unusable state is non-trivial.

Comment: @dialer: _"You know very well what the OP wants - a way to cancel a pending accept() call"_ -- the OP's code is stuck in the receiving task, not the accepting task, so closing the listening socket will have no effect. And yes, the `Socket` class has no support for cancellation tokens, but that's mainly because it's just a thin layer over the OS API, which itself has no support for cancellation tokens. So what? People complaining that the API is broken are wrong; the API is fine, closing sockets is what we did for years before .NET came along, and it still works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking against TcpListener.Pending() within your while loop first, before invoking AcceptTcpClientAsync(), this way the loop would only block if there actually is a new connection to be handled.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.pending(v=vs.110).aspx

EDIT(0): you might want to add Thread.Sleep in the while loop if you do this, to minimise CPU load

EDIT(1): so what I was aiming at was something like this:

```
while (!token.IsCancellationRequested) {
    if (_server.Pending()) {
        var client = await _server.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
        // insert code for handling new connection
    }
    Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```

The problem, as you described it, seems to be that "await AcceptTcpClientAsync()" blocks the while loop indefinitely, until a new client attempts to connect to the server.

As @Damien_The_Unbeliever pointed out in his comment, you could unblock it (in a dirty manner) by simply providing the TcpListener with a new client connection.

The above example should however - practically - execute the cancellation as soon as Thread.Sleep expires

Comment: But this still doesn't allow me to get what I want.

Comment: See above EDIT(1)

Comment: @MichaelJagroep using `Sleep` thread with socket is not recommendable because it blocks the I/O Channel of sockets, or any I/O stream, and thus the performance of program will be affected.